# Raise Android Compose Topbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In Android Compose, please tell me how to hide LazyColumn so that TopBar disappears when I raise LazyColumn

```kotlin
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            PostTopBar()
        }
    ){ innerPadding ->
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalOverscrollConfiguration provides null
        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(innerPadding)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                items(postData.size) {
                    Column {
                        Post(postData = postData[it], index = it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrong

Comment: Collpasing toolbar android??

Comment: I have a question